# Image placeholder of same aspect ratio, respecting max width & height

Tags: html, css, image

This HTML creates an image placeholder while waiting for the image to load: `<img src="http://placehold.it/1366x667" width="1366" height="667">` [1]

This CSS sets the limit of an image's size without skewing the aspect ratio[2]:

`img {
  max-width: 50%;
  max-height: 50vh;
}`

But when I use both together, it doesn't keep the aspect ratio.[3]

What can I do so that the image is correctly-sized, maintaining aspect ratio, before it is fetched?  I would prefer to do it in pure CSS, but that's not a requirement.  I have already tried setting CSS `width` and `height` to `auto` but then the image size seems to be unknown before fetching the image.

[1] http://jsbin.com/poluyociya/1/edit?html,css,output

[2] http://jsbin.com/yejezafiqi/1/edit?html,css,output

[3] http://jsbin.com/diruromela/3/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need something like this:

```css
img {
  max-width: 50%;
  height:auto;
  /*To check if aspect-ratio is preserved*/
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="http://placehold.it/1366x667" width="1366" height="667">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you get that to work with `max-height: 50vh` as well?  Once I add that, it loses its aspect ratio.

Comment: The placeholder is unfortunately 24x24 in your fiddle.  (Firefox 46)  It is only after the image header is fetched that it is correctly sized.  On a page with lots of images, there would be a lot of movement as the images are fetched.

Comment: The only other option that comes to my mind is using JavaScript to read the width/height attributes and doing ratio/limit calculation based on those values